# Pirobox gallery not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, image-gallery

For my website I am using Pirobox extended v1.3 as found here:

http://jquery.pirolab.it/pirobox/

However, I cannot close any of my images, and when I click off an image (to the side if one), they do not close.

My website and the gallery can be found using this link:

http://photo.johnvas.com/portfolio-animals.php

All my scripts can be found on the website, but to make things easier I will provide the relevant ones here:

http://photo.johnvas.com/scripts/js/pirobox_extended-1.3.js

http://photo.johnvas.com/styles/css_pirobox/style_8/style.css

I am also using the following jQuery scripts on my page:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js

http://photo.johnvas.com/scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js

Lastly, when on each page I have the following script for Pirobox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutQuart";
    $.pirobox_ext({
        attribute: 'rel',
        piro_speed : 700,
        bg_alpha : .4,
        resize : true,
        zoom_mode : true,
        move_mode : 'mousemove',
        piro_scroll : false,
        share: true
        });

    $('.source_code').hide();
    $('.tabs li a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var tabs = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').children('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if(!$(tabs).is(':visible')){
            $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').parent('.section').find('.demo').fadeOut(0);
            $(tabs).fadeIn(300);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

As stated above, none of the images allow me to close them, however they did once work and it has been nearly a year since I last accessed this site and cannot find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using previous jQuery libraries.

I was using the latest one, taken direct from the website, however, they must have updated it since the last year I used this website and it caused the gallery to break.